# Xcode 11: How to enable/fix live Interacting preview option of Xcode (for attached live preview on apple device)?

Tags: macos, xcode

I am trying to get Interaction of my swiftUI interface live on my attached  iPad Pro(Running iOS 13) but its not working. It [can be seen in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWOLW.png) that it is (gray scaled) disabled (in WWDC it was blue). Is this a bug or I am missing any step.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6WJE.png)